# Explanation of a Java linked list class definition

Tags: java, data-structures

I was given the following Java class definition to implement a single linked list program but I cannot get the full idea. I have written comments in the code poiting out my questions about it.

```
// ******************************************************************
//                      Definition of class Node<T>.
// ******************************************************************
public final class Node<T>
{
    // This is a class with "generics" where T represents a type.
    // A final class cannot be extended.
    // A final variable behaves like a constant and can only be initialized at the time it is
    // declared or within a constructor.

    // I suppose this is the value of the node.
    public final T v; 

    // I do not understand this. How is "next" defined "recursively"?
    // Please help me visualize this situation.
    // Can this variable indicate the end of the list, maybe with a null value?
    public Node<T> next;

    // Constructor.
    public Node (T val, Node<T> link) {v = val; next = link}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// I suppose this is the value of the node.
public final T v;
```

Yes. `Node` is a [parameterized class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) where the type of actual data it is holding is called `T`. So the value of the node is a variable having this type `T`. We could have a `Node<Integer>` which holds `Integer` value but also a `Node<String>` which would hold a String value. `Node` will behave the same way.

```
// I do not understand this. How is "next" defined "recursively"?
// Please help me visualize this situation.
// Can this variable indicate the end of the list, maybe with a null value?
public Node<T> next;
```

In a linked list, one node points to the next node in the list. This is why it is called "linked" list: there is a chain of elements all linked together. We might say it is defined recursively because one node points the next node, which in turn points to the next-next node, etc.

When the end is reached, there is no next node so it is `null`: the last element is the one having `next = null`. Note that there might not be a last element: one node could point to the first one and it would create a circular list.

As an example, let's say you want to build a linked list of 2 integer elements. The first element will be 1 followed by 3. You could write the following:

```
Node<Integer> firstElement = new Node<>(1, new Node<>(3, null));
// here firstElement.v will be 1 and firstElement.next.v will be 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I have the idea. The goal is to iterate a list of Node<T> with a "for each" statement so I will implement Iterator and Iterable interfaces, I will not write code to insert items, this will be done "manually" in "main" and then I will call a method to display the items in the list. I know I must instantiate a class of type Node<T>, something like this: "Node<Integer> list = new Node<Integer>();" but I cannot visualize how to add items (integers in this case). How can I add, for example, 5 nodes of type integer?

Comment: @user3059248 See the edit I made earlier. I added a code sample to create a list of 2 integer elements.

Comment: So, first node has value=1 and pointer=3, second node has value=3 and pointer=null. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3059248 the first node has value 1 and as `next` has a node that has value 3 with no next element.

Comment: If I am going to get every item using a "foreach" loop I suppose I must have a list. Of course, this functionality will be available after implementing Iterator and Iterable interfaces. I am sorry but I do get the idea about how to create a list of type Node<T>. I am lost with this issue.

Comment: @user3059248 You are probably confused because there is no `List` element here. But it's normal: one `Node` points to the next `Node`, this by itself create a "list", that is to say a sequence of elements.